# How to add categorical variable to dataframe consisting of different intervals?

Tags: r, if-statement, rstudio

I have a data frame with the variable winprop, it ranges from 0 to 1 and shows the win probability for a candidate. Now I want to add a categorical variable based on winprop to my dataset which is 'very clear' if winprop is between 0 and  0.2 and => 0.9, "clear" if winprop is between 0.2 and <= 0.4 and >0.6 and <0.9, "close race" if winprop is between 0.4 and 0.6.

I've tried to use the ifelse statement but receive error messages

```
vote_pol$closeness <- ifelse(vote_pol$winprop < 0.2 & vote_pol$winprop >= 0.9, 'very clear'),
                         ifelse(vote_pol$winprop 0.2:<0.4 & vote_pol$winprop 0.6:<0.9, 'clear',
                                ifelse(vote_pol$winprop 0.4:0.6, 'open race')

candidate winprop closeness
A         0.154   very clear
B         0.548   open race
C         0.992   very clear
D         0.745   clear  
E         0.325   clear
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. You can use `dput(vote_pol)`. Instead of complacted nested `ifelse()`, you could use `cut()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to alter this a little:

- The second `ifelse` statement should go in the bracket of the first statement, after the third comma.
- To test if a value is between two points you need to add `&` and `|` parts, with brackets for clarity (alternatively use `data.table::between` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.8/topics/between).
- The third one isn't necessary, as it should account for all remaining values.

Try this code with your data:

```
vote_pol$closeness <- ifelse(vote_pol$winprop < 0.2 | vote_pol$winprop >= 0.9, 'very clear',
    ifelse((vote_pol$winprop >= 0.2 & vote_pol$winprop < 0.4) |
         (vote_pol$winprop > 0.6 & vote_pol$winprop < 0.9), 'clear',
         'open race'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Baxter, you're tips helped!